# Rails 3: How to get all Posts which ids are not in a given list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

To get all posts with `publisher_id` equals to 10, 16, or 17, I do:

```
Post.where(:publisher_id => [10, 16, 17])
```

How would I get all posts with `publisher_id` **not equals** to 10, 16, or 17 (i.e. all possible ids besides those three) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just perform a :

```
Post.where(["publisher_id NOT IN (?)", [10, 16, 17]])
```

Comment: I'm not sure why an extra `[]` are needed. This works fine: `Post.where("publisher_id NOT IN (?)", [10, 16, 17])`. Thanks!

Comment: Just an old habit from the Rails 2 previous syntax with the :conditions option ;) You're welcome.

Answer (score 12):

in rails 4 we can do like below

```
Post.where.not(:publisher_id => [10, 16, 17])
```

it will generate SQL like below

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE ("posts"."publisher_id" NOT IN (10, 16, 17))
```

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but should be like (using metawhere gem):

```
Post.where( :id.not_eq => [10,16,17] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "pure" ActiveRecord syntax sprinkled with Arel using Rails 3 you can do something like this:

```
Post.where( Post.arel_table[:publisher_id].not_in([10, 16, 17]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Every single answer on this page is wrong because none of these answers take care of ALL array cases, **Especially arrays that have only one element**.

Here is an example that will **FAIL** using any of the 'so called' solutions on this page:

```
@ids = [1]
Post.where("publisher_id NOT IN (?)", @ids)
#ERROR
Post.where("publisher_id NOT IN (?)", [4])
#ERROR
#...etc

#ALSO
@ids = []
Post.where("publisher_id NOT IN (?)", @ids)
#ERROR
Post.where("publisher_id NOT IN (?)", [])
#ERROR
#...etc

#The problem here is that when the array only has one item, only that element is 
#returned, NOT an array, like we had specified

#Part of the sql that is generated looks like:
#...WHERE (publisher_id NOT IN 166)

#It should be:
#...WHERE (publisher_id NOT IN (166))
```

The only answer on this page that is actually on the right track and takes care of this very important case is @Tudor Constantin's. But the problem is he didn't actually show a 'way' of using his methodology to solve the real abstract example question the OP posted (not just using the hard-coded numbers).

here is my solution to dynamically find the ids not in an Activerecord association given an array of ids to exclude, that will work with an array of n elements (...including n=1 and n=0)

```
@ids = [166]
@attribute = "publisher_id"
@predicate = "NOT IN"
@ids = "(" + @ids.join(",") + ")"
if @ids == "()"
  #Empty array, just set @ids, @attribute, and @predicate to nil
  @ids = @attribute = @predicate = nil
end

#Finally, make the query
Post.where( [@attribute, @predicate, @ids].join(" ") ) 

#Part of the sql that is generated looks like:
#...WHERE (publisher_id NOT IN (166))
#CORRECT!

#If we had set @ids = []     (empty array)
#Then the if statement sets everything to nil, and then
#rails removes the blank "  " space in the where clause automatically and does
#the query as if all records should be returned, which
#logically makes sense!
```

Answer (score 0):

Neat solution I've used:

```
ids = #however you get the IDS
Post.where(["id not in (?)", [0,*ids])
```

- The presence of the 0 means it always has one element in (assuming nothing has an ID of 0)
- ID becoming a splat means it'll always be an array.

Answer (score -2):

```
Post.where(" id NOT IN ( 10, 16, 17) ")
```